# IBM Domino Expired Internet Password

Tags: lotus-domino

I have implemented password expiry for my website.  If a user has an expired password, then I would like to redirect the user to a specific form where I then resend a random password.

To do this, I have:

- setup a form with a WebQuerySave agent that changes the password using the AdminP ChangeHTTPPassword method
- set the custom form to load in the domcfg database
- made the form a public access form, and the agent runs on behalf of an admin account

The issue I have, is that the user appears to get stuck in a loop of wanting the password changed (names.nsf?ChangePassword) and will not even let me redirect the user to complete a new form from that will then kick off the password reset etc.  This includes a link to my password reminder page that sends the user their password.

These are external users, and I am using directory assistance.  I do not use the ID vault here.

Is it possible to get out of this loop?
If not, then is it possible to add an agent to run when the standard password reset works?

Comment: It is not enough to make the form public You should check, if the user "Anonymous" 
 may read public documents in the database. (This Is an option in the DB ACL)